# iOS SwiftUI - closing view / dismiss() causes crash Thread 23: EXC_BREAKPOINT

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have this in the main view:

```
@Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss

func closeLogin(){
    self.dismiss()
}
```

and I pass this function to a subview and there I try to call it from within another function:

```
func tryLogin() async throws {

    guard let url =  URL(string: domain + "/do_login.php") else { return }
    
    var postString = "&email=" + String(inputEmail)
    postString += "&password=" + String(password)
    
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

    let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
    if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any] {

        if(json["passed"] as! Int == 1){
            
            if let uid = json["userid"] as? Int {
                userid = uid
            }

            closeLogin() // <<<<
        }
    }
}
```

I get

```
Thread 23: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1861b7e5c)
```

on

```
self.dismiss()
```

Please help

Comment: I think you are trying to access the ``main thread`` from the background ``DispatchQueue.main.async { }`` should fix your problem

Comment: It works, doesn't crash any more, thanks! Please give this as answer and I'll check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it based on a comment here:

```
func closeLogin(){
    DispatchQueue.main.async { 
        self.dismiss()
    }
}
```